# What's the Word For Having Influence via a Second Party

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a word that succinctly describes one person's impact on many through others.  My real life example is a coach.  The coach taught me directly.  I coached my daughter, using what I learned.  My daughter has now improved.  The coach influenced my daughter through me, though they have never met.

Because the coach is so skilled, so motivated, so passionate she has influenced many over time, often through intermediaries.  I would like to say the teacher's passion/motivation/knowledge is .....

I thought of exponential, but it wasn't quite correct.
I thought of transitive, but it wasn't quite correct.

Like the old commercial, "and she told two friends, and she told two friends,etc."

Many thanks.

Comment: Also, in academia at least, for your coach-you-daughter example, they went for the straightforward *[genealogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_genealogy)*, where mentors and proteges correspond to parents and children respectively. But this only applies to tree structures; your "telephone game" example seems to me to be a more general graph. You might find something apt if you dig into the concept of "six degrees". In the Tipping Point, Gladwell calls people with a large number of social connections *[Connectors](http://bit.ly/29hP0an)*, quite straightforwardly.

Comment: Thanks Dan - I was just reading about Three Degrees of Influence. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_degrees_of_influence

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 2):

The coach has impacted your daughters life through his

> **indirect influence**
>
> effecting change through another agent, vicarious effect
>
> [dictionarist](http://www.dictionarist.com/indirect+influence)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I did think of indirect influence, but I was hoping for a single word.  I appreciate the definition link as well.

Comment: The question is still open.  If someone finds something to beat it, it'll get the most votes.  Some single words don't exist.  Even when they do, sometimes a pair beats a single word.

Answer (score 2):

While not an adjective, you could say the coach has created a *[legacy](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=legacy)*

> Something handed down from an ancestor or a predecessor or from the past: *a legacy of religious freedom.*

*American Heritage*